# Code optimization (combine 2 lines of code into 1)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried some combinations but can't seem to get it right. I am looking to combine line 2 and 3 into one line of code.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == 'SSM M51 Copperhead'"];
NSArray *searchResults1 = [self.weaponsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
weapons = [searchResults1 objectAtIndex:0];
if(weapons.range > SSMrange)
    SSMrange = weapons.range;
```

('weapons' is a class).

Comment: Why?  What do you expect to gain?  (Not that it's particularly hard to do.)  "Daisy chaining" levels of access together makes the code harder to debug, harder to understand, and does not improve performance.

Comment: Looking to cut out some code. I have a lot of these in the project I am working right now and was looking for a better way to write the code.

Comment: The way it is written is the better way. Combining it all is not the better way. Remember: less lines != better code.

Comment: If you have lots of them, maybe you need to learn how to do subroutines.  What you're discussing above is *not* "optimization" (not even "premature optimization").

Comment: @HotLicks and rmaddy - Thanks. Optimization was obviously the wrong word to use but I see your points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
weapons = [self.weaponsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate][0];
```

This isn't really going to make your code any faster though.

Comment: I know but I am always looking to simply code wherever I can.

Comment: Could also use `[[self.weaponsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] objectAtIndex:0]` for readability.

Comment: Just remember, changing the original code to this new code makes it harder to read and harder to debug. Think about the need to inspects the results of the predicate.

Answer (score 2):

How about defining a method like:

```
- (Weapon*)firstWeaponMatchingPredicateWithFormat:(NSString*)format
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format];
    NSArray *searchResults1 = [self.weaponsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return (searchResults1.count > 0 ? [searchResults1 objectAtIndex:0] : nil);
}
```

Call with:

```
Weapon *weapon = [self firstWeaponMatchingPredicateWithFormat:@"name == 'SSM M51 Copperhead'"];
```

Comment: Thanks @Taum. Guess I'm too deep in the forest to see the trees. Your example makes more sense. Had to give the right answer to hypercrypt though because he did answer my stated question first.

Answer (score 1):

```
weapon = [[self.weaponsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create an array object with the filtered results only to get the first object and throw away the collection.

If you're targeting iOS 4.0 or later, `NSArray` provides functionality to get the index of the first object passing a test through a block.

```
NSUInteger indexOfObject = [self.weaponsArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
  return [[obj valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"SSM M51 Copperhead"];
}];
```

The block will be executed once for each object and the array will stop processing when the block returns `YES`.  Once you know the index of the object, you can get the value directly from you `self.weaponsArray` array.  Just make sure you check the return value for `NSNotFound`.

I tried filtering an array of 1,000,000 objects and searching for the both the first and last object using the two approaches. Even when looking for the last object, the block approach was still quicker than using a predicate.  I'm guessing due to the saving of not creating a filtered array.